# Are there any tools to automatically take screenshots of the webpage my user is in, while she reports bugs?

Tags: javascript, screenshot

My website has a feedback form. I'd like to attach screen shot of the current page the user is in, with the press of a button. Are there any tools/libraries that can do this?

Comment: you can print screen, then paste into a contentEditable. the paste won't actually insert an image by default, but the paste event will have access to the copied image data: http://pagedemos.com/9nz6j6xnuh9z/output/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

This seems to solve your issue if you attach it to the onClick event of the bug report button.